# Switch child components by state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      SignUpClicked: null
    };
    this.openSignUp = this.openSignUp.bind(this)
  }


  openSignUp() {
    this.setState({
      SignUpClicked: true
    })
    console.log('signup clicked')
  }

  render() {
      return (
      <div> 
        <SignUp
        authState={this.props.authState}
        onStateChange={this.props.onStateChange}
        openSignUp = {this.openSignUp} />
        <SignIn
        authState={this.props.authState}
        onStateChange={this.props.onStateChange} />
      </div>)
      }
    }

export default Parent;
```

and then two child components SignUp & SignIn in different files.

In each of them there's a link like `<p>Sign Up Instead?<a href="#" onClick = {this.props.openSignUp}> Sign Up </a></p>`  and the other way for Sign In.

However, I can't get them to switch between the two components - what am I doing wrong  here?

Comment: The best way is to assign two routes to the components and change the route path by clicking on the switch links.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily control which component should be rendered by putting condition with them. If `this.props.authState` is true, show SignUp component else show SignIn component

```
 <div> 
        {!this.props.authState && (<SignUp
        authState={this.props.authState}
        onStateChange={this.props.onStateChange}
        openSignUp = {this.openSignUp} />) }
        {this.props.authState && (<SignIn
        authState={this.props.authState}
        onStateChange={this.props.onStateChange} />)}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called [conditional rendering](https://scotch.io/tutorials/7-ways-to-implement-conditional-rendering-in-react-applications) you can use that can solve your problem. Simply put in `conditional rendering` you display a component only when a condition is met. In your case, you can try the following.

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      SignUpClicked: false
    };
  
  }

//changed this to arrow function that binds "this" automatically
  toggleSignUp = () => {
    this.setState({
      SignUpClicked: !this.state.SignUpClicked
    })
    console.log('signup clicked')
  }

  render() {
      return (
      <div> 
       { this.state.SignUpClicked && 
       <SignUp
        authState={this.props.authState}
        onStateChange={this.props.onStateChange}
        openSignIn = {this.toggleSignUp} />
        }
        
        {!this.state.SignUpClicked &&
        <SignIn
        authState={this.props.authState}
        onStateChange={this.props.onStateChange} 
        openSignUp = {this.toggleSignUp} />
        />
        }
      </div>
      )}
    }

export default Parent;
```

> **NOTE: Pay attention to the changes I have done**

1. Changed the function to [arrow function](https://medium.com/@oleg008/arrow-functions-in-react-f782d11460b4) by using them you don't have to bind `this` in `constructor`. It automatically does that for you.
2. I have changed the name of function `openSignUp` to `toggleSignUp` because we will use a single function to display signup component and than hide it if we want. (because I assume you will implement "sign in instead" in `<SignUp/>` component to get back to sign in
3. I have passed the same `toggleSignUp` function reference to both the components so that you can show or hide either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Set state of the component
    this.state = {
      // Show sign in page by default
      show: "signin"
    };
  }


  showSignup = () => {
    // Show sign up page by changing the show variable
    this.setState({
      show: "signup"
    });

    console.log('Showing Signup Page');
  }

  showSignin = () => {
    // Show sign in page by changing the show variable
    this.setState({
      show: "signin"
    });

    console.log('Showing Signin Page');
  }

  render() {
      // Render the component as per show state variable
      if(this.state.show === "signin") {
          return <SignIn 
                     authState={this.props.authState} 
                     onStateChange={this.props.onStateChange} 
                     onSignup={this.showSignup} 
          />
      }
      else {
          return <SignUp
                     authState={this.props.authState} 
                     onSignup={this.showSignin} 
          />

      }
  }

export default Parent;
```

So basically, export onClick event from both the child components and set show variable of state in parent component. Then depending upon the state, return only the component you want.

Please let me know if there is any question or confusion. Would love to answer.